# What are the limitations of Gitlab Community Edition (Gitlab CE)?

Tags: gitlab, estimation, gitlab-ce

I read this comparison https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/self-managed/feature-comparison/ on Gitlab, lot of things are still unclear. I would like to ask about the limitation at some points:

1. limitation for general element type (number of people, project, ...) of Gitlab?
2. using Gitlab CE for git repositories hosting, are there any limitation of

   - number of repo
   - repo size
   - number of commit
   - number of users,
3. For ticket system, any limitation in

   - number of issues
   - number of boards ...
4. using CI/CD, any limitation of runners, pipelines, executors, number of projects, number of environments ...

Comment: There're no limits.

Answer (score 3):

General differences between CE and EE can be found on [GitLab website](https://about.gitlab.com/install/ce-or-ee/).

Additionally, [GitLab pricing page](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/) outlines the differences between various plans. If you are running CE, you are running Free plan, so that is the column which will apply to you.

To address your question specifically, most, if not all, of the stuff you asked about will be the same both for CE and EE, there are no limits in terms of numbers. Main difference (aside from the codebase) is the feature set, which is outlined on the second link I shared.